# String to bits String Erlang

Tags: string, erlang, bit

I have tried to use `bitstring` but with no success

I need to convert a `String` to (String of bits), 8 bits for each char

For example:

```
"hi" = "0110100001101001"
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a string and not know the encoding of that string. I assume you want UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try binary comprehensions

```
[C + $0 || <<C:1>> <= list_to_binary(String)]
```

For instance

```
[C + $0 || <<C:1>> <= list_to_binary("hi")].
"0110100001101001"
```

Comment: also check this if you need binary: `<< <<(C + $0)/integer>> || <<C:1>> <= <<"hi">> >>. `

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use [formatting](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fwrite-1) using [io_lib:format](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#format-2)

```
lists:flatten([io_lib:format("~8.2.0B", [Char]) || Char <- String]).
"0110100001101001"
```